# hiding windows command line args

Tags: command-line-arguments

I want to run a windows app (the 'target') from another app (the 'runner')

I dont own the target.

Is there any way I can do this without having the params I pass show up in process explorer (I am passing a password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way. If I understand well you want to pass a password in CLEARTEXT to the target. The only way to not have it show would be for the target program to look for some file where the password is stored, or to look for some key to read the encrypted password.

I assume that by not owning the target you can't ask for that modification to be made. Your best luck would be looking into the manual of the target app

i hope it was useful

Comment: This is not the case - it is possible (CyberArk for instance does this) but the mechanism does not appear to be well documented - I came across this discusion when trying to find out fr myself how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blog post and comment thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/23/9440784.aspx).  Indicates a method under which one process can get at the command line of another.  Could the runner launch the process, then go in after some interval (allowing the launched process to first make use of the command line parameters) and change the command line, so that the reported command line is not the original?